# Iterate through JSON array and record certain values

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to iterate through this JSON array and record the num-of-connections value if it is greater than 0, then, if it is greater than 0 record the owner and their last-disconnection-time and store them to be output to the console once the script is done.

I have tried for loops and while loops but cannot figure out how to record certain values and get the other values to be output to the console at the end of the script.

```
[
  {
    "id" : "123456",
    "owner" : "johndoe",
    "x11-display" : ":9",
    "x11-authority" : "/run/user/1112/dcv/123456.xauth",
    "num-of-connections" : 1,
    "creation-time" : "2019-05-28T14:42:24.027240Z",
    "last-disconnection-time" : "2019-05-30T21:47:36.682935Z"
  },
  {
    "id" : "12345",
    "owner" : "johnsmith",
    "x11-display" : ":5",
    "x11-authority" : "/run/user/user/dcv/12345.xauth",
    "num-of-connections" : 0,
    "creation-time" : "2019-05-14T14:12:14.989287Z",
    "last-disconnection-time" : "2019-05-31T18:58:42.851223Z"
  }
]
```

What I want is a summary at the end of the script that says something like this .

user $owner has $num-of-connections open connections and last disconnected at $last-disconnection-time .

I want this only if the num-of-connections is greater than 0. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your sample isn't valid JSON, btw.

Comment: Remove the last comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
jq -r '.[] | select(."num-of-connections" > 0) | "User \(.owner) has \(."num-of-connections") open connections and last disconnected at \(."last-disconnection-time")."' test.json
```

which on your fixed up sample data prints out:

```
User johndoe has 1 open connections and last disconnected at 2019-05-30T21:47:36.682935Z.
```

Comment: Ahh, I did not know you could add in logic with a jq query. That is very helpful. This works great thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for because the requested output is not clear to me, but you can go with this one-liner

```
jq '.[] | select(."num-of-connections">0) | {"owner": ."owner", "num-of-connections": ."num-of-connections", "last-disconnection-time": ."last-disconnection-time"}' input.json
```

or this

```
jq -r '.[] | select(."num-of-connections">0) | "\(.owner) \(."num-of-connections") \(."last-disconnection-time")"' input.json
```

Comment: This and Shawn's work exactly the same. Thank you very much!